# Функция уменьшения изображения на PHP

Tags: php

Нашел в интернете отличную функцию, которая уменьшает изображения, обрезает и т.д. Но недостаток в том, что она почему-то поворачивает изображение на 90 градусов. Не могу разобраться почему. Не вижу в коде поворота.

```
public function smart_resize_image($file,
                            $string             = null,
                            $width              = 0,
                            $height             = 0,
                            $proportional       = false,
                            $output             = 'file',
                            $delete_original    = true,
                            $use_linux_commands = false,
                            $quality = 100
) {

    if ( $height <= 0 && $width <= 0 ) return false;
    if ( $file === null && $string === null ) return false;

    # Setting defaults and meta
    $info                         = $file !== null ? getimagesize($file) : getimagesizefromstring($string);
    $image                        = '';
    $final_width                  = 0;
    $final_height                 = 0;
    list($width_old, $height_old) = $info;
    $cropHeight = $cropWidth = 0;

    # Calculating proportionality
    if ($proportional) {
        if      ($width  == 0)  $factor = $height/$height_old;
        elseif  ($height == 0)  $factor = $width/$width_old;
        else                    $factor = min( $width / $width_old, $height / $height_old );

        $final_width  = round( $width_old * $factor );
        $final_height = round( $height_old * $factor );
    }
    else {
        $final_width = ( $width <= 0 ) ? $width_old : $width;
        $final_height = ( $height <= 0 ) ? $height_old : $height;
        $widthX = $width_old / $width;
        $heightX = $height_old / $height;

        $x = min($widthX, $heightX);
        $cropWidth = ($width_old - $width * $x) / 2;
        $cropHeight = ($height_old - $height * $x) / 2;
    }

    # Loading image to memory according to type
    switch ( $info[2] ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  $file !== null ? $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) : $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);  break;
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:   $file !== null ? $image = imagecreatefromgif($file)  : $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);  break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:   $file !== null ? $image = imagecreatefrompng($file)  : $image = imagecreatefromstring($string);  break;
        default: return false;
    }


    # This is the resizing/resampling/transparency-preserving magic
    $image_resized = imagecreatetruecolor( $final_width, $final_height );
    if ( ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) ) {
        $transparency = imagecolortransparent($image);
        $palletsize = imagecolorstotal($image);

        if ($transparency >= 0 && $transparency < $palletsize) {
            $transparent_color  = imagecolorsforindex($image, $transparency);
            $transparency       = imagecolorallocate($image_resized, $transparent_color['red'], $transparent_color['green'], $transparent_color['blue']);
            imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $transparency);
            imagecolortransparent($image_resized, $transparency);
        }
        elseif ($info[2] == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {
            imagealphablending($image_resized, false);
            $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image_resized, 0, 0, 0, 127);
            imagefill($image_resized, 0, 0, $color);
            imagesavealpha($image_resized, true);
        }
    }
    imagecopyresampled($image_resized, $image, 0, 0, $cropWidth, $cropHeight, $final_width, $final_height, $width_old - 2 * $cropWidth, $height_old - 2 * $cropHeight);


    # Taking care of original, if needed
    if ( $delete_original ) {
        if ( $use_linux_commands ) exec('rm '.$file);
        else @unlink($file);
    }

    # Preparing a method of providing result
    switch ( strtolower($output) ) {
        case 'browser':
            $mime = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);
            header("Content-type: $mime");
            $output = NULL;
            break;
        case 'file':
            $output = $file;
            break;
        case 'return':
            return $image_resized;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    # Writing image according to type to the output destination and image quality
    switch ( $info[2] ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:   imagegif($image_resized, $output);    break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:  imagejpeg($image_resized, $output, $quality);   break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $quality = 9 - (int)((0.9*$quality)/10.0);
            imagepng($image_resized, $output, $quality);
            break;
        default: return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// вызов
$result = smart_resize_image($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], null, 1000, 1000, true, $path.$filename, true, false, 100);
```

Comment: Посмотрите ответ насчёт EXIF заголовков [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774411/php-resizing-image-on-upload-rotates-the-image-when-i-dont-want-it-to)

Answer (score 1):

По комменту:

*Автор скриптов Михаил Русаков.

Код функции масштабирования изображения на PHP:

```
<?php
  /*
  $w_o и h_o - ширина и высота выходного изображения
  */
  function resize($image, $w_o = false, $h_o = false) {
    if (($w_o < 0) || ($h_o < 0)) {
      echo "Некорректные входные параметры";
      return false;
    }
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($image); // Получаем размеры и тип изображения (число)
    $types = array("", "gif", "jpeg", "png"); // Массив с типами изображений
    $ext = $types[$type]; // Зная "числовой" тип изображения, узнаём название типа
    if ($ext) {
      $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext; // Получаем название функции, соответствующую типу, для создания изображения
      $img_i = $func($image); // Создаём дескриптор для работы с исходным изображением
    } else {
      echo 'Некорректное изображение'; // Выводим ошибку, если формат изображения недопустимый
      return false;
    }

    if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o / ($w_i / $h_i);
    if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o / ($h_i / $w_i);
    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o); // Создаём дескриптор для выходного изображения
    imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img_i, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i); // Переносим изображение из исходного в выходное, масштабируя его
    $func = 'image'.$ext; // Получаем функция для сохранения результата
    return $func($img_o, $image); // Сохраняем изображение в тот же файл, что и исходное, возвращая результат этой операции
  }

  resize("image.jpg", 100); // Вызываем функцию
?>
```

Функция легко позволяет сжимать и растягивать изображения на PHP, при этом при необходимости и сохранять пропорции.

Обрезание изображения в PHP:

```
<?php
  /*
  $x_o и $y_o - координаты левого верхнего угла выходного изображения на исходном
  $w_o и h_o - ширина и высота выходного изображения
  */
  function crop($image, $x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o) {
    if (($x_o < 0) || ($y_o < 0) || ($w_o < 0) || ($h_o < 0)) {
      echo "Некорректные входные параметры";
      return false;
    }
    list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($image); // Получаем размеры и тип изображения (число)
    $types = array("", "gif", "jpeg", "png"); // Массив с типами изображений
    $ext = $types[$type]; // Зная "числовой" тип изображения, узнаём название типа
    if ($ext) {
      $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext; // Получаем название функции, соответствующую типу, для создания изображения
      $img_i = $func($image); // Создаём дескриптор для работы с исходным изображением
    } else {
      echo 'Некорректное изображение'; // Выводим ошибку, если формат изображения недопустимый
      return false;
    }
    if ($x_o + $w_o > $w_i) $w_o = $w_i - $x_o; // Если ширина выходного изображения больше исходного (с учётом x_o), то уменьшаем её
    if ($y_o + $h_o > $h_i) $h_o = $h_i - $y_o; // Если высота выходного изображения больше исходного (с учётом y_o), то уменьшаем её
    $img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o); // Создаём дескриптор для выходного изображения
    imagecopy($img_o, $img_i, 0, 0, $x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o); // Переносим часть изображения из исходного в выходное
    $func = 'image'.$ext; // Получаем функция для сохранения результата
    return $func($img_o, $image); // Сохраняем изображение в тот же файл, что и исходное, возвращая результат этой операции
  }
  crop("image.jpg", 100, 100, 200, 50); // Вызываем функцию
?>
```

*В CSS есть возможность чётко задать размеры изображения, но не стоит изображение 1600×1200 выводить с размером 160×120, так как сам файл будет грузиться очень долго. Вдобавок, если требуется не просто некая ширина, но и высота, например, 150×150, то через CSS можно сильно исказить изображение, поскольку пропорции у него могут быть другие.

---

Попробуйте `$proportional = false,` поставить в `true`

Посмотрю еще - видимо, он поворачивает по длинной стороне - высоте или ширине.

Comment: не помогло к сожалению.

Comment: Вам именно этот скрипт нужен? Я пользуюсь двумя от Русакова - нет проблем. Этот просмотрел - пока не вижу поворота.

Comment: Да не обязательно этот. Лишь бы работал.

Comment: Ваш скрипт тоже почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: Они 100% рабочие - я их уже не первый год пользую. Возможно, версия PHP имеет значение...